# Whats the correct way to get Gradle to inform GroovyShell where the dependancies the script requires are?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I've finally got Gradle downloading dependancies and passing these to a groovy script that I'm calling from a gralde task (as gradle doesn't seem to allow me to use grape).

The code below is the only way I've been able to get it working.  Is this the correct way?

**build.gradle:**

```
configurations {
    shell
}

// Specify dependancies
dependencies {
    // Groovy Script task dependancies
    shell 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.6'
    shell 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.0'

    // actual application dependancies
    compile ... 
}

task cleanupArtifactory (dependsOn: configurations.shell) << {
    //Now add those dependencies to the root classLoader:
    URLClassLoader loader = GroovyObject.class.classLoader
    configurations.shell.each {File file -> loader.addURL(file.toURL()) }

    new GroovyShell().run(file('scripts/artifactory.groovy'))
}
```

Comment: I'd consider running the code in a separate JVM (e.g. using a `JavaExec` task) to avoid the class loader trickery/pollution.

Comment: Quite interesting scenario. Why don't You just put the dependencies in groovy script directly with grape? It's not working? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just treat your groovy scripts as classes and run them with JavaExec.

Here's an example

```
task yourTask(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: classes) {
    description = "Does some stuff"

    if (project.hasProperty('args')) {
        // this is just a fancy regex to get all the args from '-Pargs="-a -b -c"' and passing them to the main class
        def myArgs = (project.args =~ /([^\s"']+)|["']([^'"]*)["']/).collect{it[1] ?: it[2]}
        args myArgs
    }

    main = 'your.GroovyClass'
    classpath configurations.compile, configurations.runtime, sourceSets.main.output
}
```

The "args" bit is just so you can call the task with

```
gradle yourTask -Pargs="-a -b somevalue"
```

passing the values directly through to the class.

On the subject of grape, I have a working configuration that both allows me to call/compile the groovy class from gradle, and allow the Grab notation to work to be able to call the script directly.

In your groovy class add the appropriate grab and import, e.g.:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.6')
import groovyx.net.http.*
```

In your build.gradle for the project, add following:

```
configurations {
    ivy
}

dependencies {
    ivy 'org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.3.0'
}

tasks.withType(GroovyCompile) { groovyClasspath += configurations.ivy }
```

Now I can call the groovy script directly with

```
groovy /path/to/the/GroovyClass -a -b somevalue
```

or use the gradle task as defined earlier.

If I don't add that bit of ivy code, the class with the grab in it fails to compile through gradle.